# Script dies without error after calling mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to mysql with PHP and it doesn't work at all.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');

mysql_select_db("test_site", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");

echo $query;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My entire script stops right after the first line($con = ...). I tried adding echo "TEST"; right after that line and it didn't show. When I try to print text before that line, it works fine. Even if I add something like:

```
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

No error shows. I'm assuming that means the connection was fine... so why does my script stop? When I do the same thing through my terminal I get * from test, just like I need. Not with PHP.

Help? =]

thanks

edit:

nvm, found a way to make it work.

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: check the output of `phpinfo()`...look for `error_log` setting.

Comment: error_log: no value. However, log errors is on.

Comment: Then check the apache error log...PHP uses that by default.

Comment: Your php configuration is missing the mysql module. You need to add 'extension=mysql.so' in your php.ini file (and make sure that mysql.so is available.) What OS are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 11.04. I have 3 php.ini files, and none of them seem to have any extension = xxx that is not commented, and I suppose there should be a lot.

Comment: On Unix like OSs you must compile php from scratch with ./configure --with-mysql=/path/to/mysql option (http://it.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php). The option you are looking for is valid only for windows os

Comment: @bitfox That isn't true. Most Linux distributions come with a package manager that allows you to install compiled software, and you do have to enable modules with the extension= command in php.ini whether you are in Windows or Linux. On Windows the modules have a .dll filename and on Linux they are .so. Ubuntu has packages that will automatically set up Apache2, PHP and Mysql all working together.

Comment: @AndrewR I know. You refer to linux distributions. I referred to UNIX like OSs. However, I prefer to take the control and personalize my php installation, it is also good for learn. For Ubuntu you should try this command, if you prefer the package manager: apt-get install php5-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the php5 mysql modules. This will install the modules and set them up in PHP on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: I just read the other comments and found out you installed from source. Have a look at this page to help you install from the package manager. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: did that and restarted apache. mysql_connect is still undefined.

Comment: Right, because you compiled from source without mysql support. It will be much easier if you follow the instructions on that Ubuntu community help page.

Comment: I normally use RPM based distros. Does debian/ubuntu have mysql support as a separate package? like php-mysql?

Comment: @datasage Yes it does. php5-mysql installs the mysql.so module and sets up PHP to use it.

Comment: php5-mysql did fix the issue! Well, kinda. Now the output I'm getting is resource(3) of type (mysql result) . Error log says: [Sat Jun 11 23:46:24 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jun 11 23:46:25 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations. Updated my question with current code

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query returns a resource that cannot be converted to string for echo.

Try var_dump($query) instead.

Comment: How do you know? as your script is written right now, nothing will ever show.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my question? I said I tried printing text before and after the first line and it only worked before.

Comment: Check the values of display_errors and your error_reporting level.

Comment: I found the error, it says mysql_connect is undefined. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Then the mysql extension is not enabled. How you enable that depends on your environment and how PHP is installed.

Comment: It worked before, there's no way it's not enabled. Well that was long ago.. I did reinstall PHP a few times since then. I'm on ubuntu 11.04, how do I check for it?

Comment: Did you install it using the package manager, or compile it yourself?

Comment: With php 5.3 it should be enabled by default using the mysqlnd driver. With previous versions it needs to be enabled using --with-mysql. php_info should give you the version of php you have and what compile flags were used to build php.

Comment: php 5.3.2. I can't seem to find compile flags. Under what field are they?

Comment: In the php_info() output, they are often at the top section.

Comment: I don't see anything about compile flags. The top section says PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2(yeah it's 5.3.5, not 5.3.2. made a mistake =/)

Comment: I think its pretty clear that its not available. You will need to configure with --with-mysql or --with-mysql=mysqlnd (to enable the native driver). Personally, i would just install from the packages anyway.

Comment: So I need to reinstall PHP? damn.. took me hours to configure it

Comment: Then try using the ubuntu packages. You should get it up and running within minutes. Unless you are making modifications to the core php code, compiling is all that necessary anymore.

Comment: I can't find php in the software center.

Comment: also, I did remove --purge php5, and it still works even after restarting apache.

Answer (score -1):

You've got MySQL running on your server right? As long as you're passing the right host/user/pass it shouldn't just be flat out failing...