# Program seems to not recognize SQL Server functions

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7

We are having this exact problem but with SQL Server instead of MYSQL: [Script dies without error after calling mysql_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318078/script-dies-without-error-after-calling-mysql-connect)

(the mssql_pconnect command instead of mysql_pconnect)

However, we downloaded the dll and linked the extension in the php.ini file as suggested and it still isnt working.  We are working on a Windows 2008 Standard R2 with IIS 7.0

We're getting an "undefined function: mssql_pconnect" in the php log

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Is the MS SQL extension reprorting as loaded on a phpinfo() output?

Are you using the correct php.ini file?

And last but not least: Is your MS SQL extension compatible to your PHP version? This new question seems to say that different PHP versions need different MS SQL extensions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693100/drivers-to-communicate-with-ms-sql-database-using-php-5-5

Comment: @Mastacheata it doesnt show up on the phpinfo page. and the phpinfo output has "--without-mssql" in the configure command box.  We thought we were using the right ini file, but it doesnt seem that it is working.

Comment: That is your problem as far as the PHP documentation goes.

> To get these functions to work, you have to compile PHP
> with --with-mssql[=DIR], where DIR is the FreeTDS install prefix.
> And FreeTDS should be compiled using --enable-msdblib

Comment: if mssql doesn't show up in phpinfo(), then it's NOT enabled, and the functions will not exist.